# POST requests are being called twice in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, post, http-post

I don't know but my POST requests are being called twice. May I know the fix for this? I tried using share() too but to no avail.

The following is my code

```
 addUser(data): Observable<User> {


    let body : string = JSON.stringify(
    {postData: data}),
    headers: any = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
    options: any = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers}),
    url: any = this.Url+"/user/register";


    return this.http.post(url,body,options).map(res=> <any>(res['_body']));


}
```

[image]

Comment: This code looks fine to me, it probably happens twice because it's being called twice.

Comment: The first request is probably an OPTIONS request. Check CORS docs for more details.

Comment: Can you post the request screenshot here

Comment: @Sreemat I edited and please check the image. What Gunter Zochbauer said is true but am not able to fix it. Any help?

Comment: you are actually making only one post call. What you see is the OPTIONS request made by CHROME before it actually make post request. Check CORS docs as suggested by Gunter Zochbauer. You wont see OPTIONS request in firefox.

Comment: Can you show use case addUser method in your application?

Answer (score 0):

First request is type OPTIONS, it's normal. The HTTP OPTIONS method is used to describe the communication options for the target resource.

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: this.testServicde.addUser(this.data).subscribe(response=>{

                var result = JSON.stringify(response); } This is my usecase

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ul38INLymPzSJ6cHbk7U?p=catalogue I added in plunker. Can you please check?

Comment: Ok, can you paste the request screenshot here(from developer console in chrome)

Comment: Hah, I don't see when you update question. I updated my answer too :)